# Jquery If a checkbox is checked disable other checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a group of php generated checkboxes :

```
<?php foreach($checkbox as $check) {?>
<input type = "checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="<?php echo $check -> class ?>" value ="<?php echo $check -> value ?>" /><?php echo $check->value ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Above PHP generates HTML below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="class1" value="Checkbox1" />Checkbox1
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="class1" value="Checkbox2" />Checkbox2
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="class1" value="Checkbox3" />Checkbox3

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="class2" value="Checkbox4" />Checkbox4
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="class2" value="Checkbox5" />Checkbox5
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="class2" value="Checkbox6" />Checkbox6

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="class3" value="Checkbox7" />Checkbox7
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="class3" value="Checkbox8" />Checkbox8
```

To explain above, I have three classes of checkboxes, and would like that:

If I check any in `class1`, `class3` becomes disabled, if I uncheck, `class3` is back enabled.
If I check `class2` , all of the other `class2` become disabled, `class1` remains checked if already checked, becomes checked if not.

I have tried doing this, using the Script below.

```
$('input[class*="class"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        var classValue = $(this).attr('class');
        if(classValue == 'class1'){
            $('.class3').prop('disabled', true);
            $('.class3').prop('checked', false);
        }
        else if(classValue == 'class2'){

            $('.class2').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
            $('.class3').prop('disabled', true);
        }

        else if(classValue == 'class3'){

            $('.class1').prop('checked', false);
            $('.class2').prop('checked', false);
            $('.class1, .class2').prop('disabled', true);

        }

    }

})
```

Doesn't work though.

Comment: Your question doesn't say what should happen when checking `class3`, but your code has this case in it. Which is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('input[class^="class"]').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(".class1")) {
        if ($(".class1:checked").length > 0) {
            $(".class3").prop({ disabled: true, checked: false });
        } else {
            $(".class3").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    } else if ($this.is(".class2")) {
        if ($this.is(":checked")) {
            $(".class2").not($this).prop({ disabled: true, checked: false });
            $(".class1").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $(".class2").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/rn6Va/)

Comment: This works great. I'm trying to do something similar where checking a "Checkbox Z" disables the other checkboxes. However, I need to add the functionality that re-enables those boxes and restores the checks if "Checkbox Z" is unchecked again. Let me know if anyone has any ideas on that.

Comment: You can save the old state in a `data` attribute. Then when they uncheck Z, go through all the other checkboxes and check or uncheck them based on that attribute.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. That's out of my realm of knowledge, so I'll do some research on data attributes.

Answer (score 4):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/EACk4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.class1').on('change', function(){        
        if($('.class1:checked').length){
            //or $('.class3').prop({disabled: 'disabled', checked: false});
            $('.class3').prop('disabled', true);
            $('.class3').prop('checked', false);
            return;
        }

        $('.class3').prop('disabled', false);
    });

    $('.class2').on('change', function(){
        if(!$(this).prop('checked')){
            $('.class2').prop('disabled', false);
            return;
        }
        $('.class2').prop('disabled', true);
        $(this).prop('disabled', false);

        !$('.class1:checked').length ? $('.class1').click() : '';
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code a bit -- I think it accomplishes what you wanted.

```
$('input[class*="class"]').click(function(){

var classValue = $(this).attr('class')
    ,isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

if(classValue == 'class1'){ 
    if( !isChecked && $('.' + classValue + ':checked').length > 0 ) {
        return;
    }
    $('.class3').prop('disabled', isChecked ? true : false);
    $('.class3').prop('checked', isChecked ? false : null);
}
else if(classValue == 'class2'){
    if( isChecked && $('.class1 :checked').length <= 0 ){
        $('.class1').prop('checked', true);  
    }
     $('.class2').not(':checked').prop('disabled', isChecked ? true : false); 
    $('.class3').prop('disabled', isChecked ? true : false);
}
else if(classValue == 'class3'){

    $('.class1, .class2').prop('checked', isChecked ? false : null);
    $('.class1, .class2').prop('disabled', isChecked ? true  : false);   
}
```

})

Comment: On second thought, @Barmar appears to have a more efficient working example. I haven't really used jQuery before.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question that I found useful - THANKS!

I modified this a bit for a more simple use case... where you just want to have a list of choices where one choice unchecks and disables all others. Unchecking the choice that fires the condition will reenable the other choices

Sample HTML

```
Chooose one:<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="choices-1" class="n_remove" value="1" />choice 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="choices-2" class="n_remove" value="2" />choice 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="choices-3" class="n_remove" value="3" />choice 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="choices-1" class="n_check" value="4" />none of the above<br />
```

Sample javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.n_check').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(".n_check")) {
            if ($(".n_check:checked").length > 0) {
                $(".n_remove").prop({ disabled: true, checked: false });
            } else {
                $(".n_remove").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/xkyucg6L/